# Noncompact three-manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to a surface group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M$ be an open orientable three-manifold such that $\pi_1 (M)$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a closed orientable surface $S\ncong \mathbb{S}^2$. Furthermore, suppose that $\tilde{M} \cong \mathbb{R}^3$. Is it true that $M \cong S \times \mathbb{R}$?

Without making any assumptions about $\tilde{M}$, there are counterexamples to the question, ([see for instance...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734107/a-3-manifold-with-fundamental-group-isomorphic-to-a-surface-group) ), but in those cases the universal cover is not very nice.

[As remarked by several commentators, you need $S$ to be orientable.  I added this hypothesis and fixed some of the notation. - Sam]

Comment: Is the equality sign supposed to mean "is homeomorphic to"?

Comment: @YCor yes, sorry for the vagueness

Comment: $M$ could be a nontrivial line bundle over $S$. Maybe you want to assume that both $S$ and $M$ are orientable--and also that $S$ is not the sphere.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie yes you are right, I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: As @TomGoodwillie's comment says, you also need to assume that the surface $S$ is orientable: there are orientable non-trivial line bundles over non-orientable surfaces.  The simplest such example is a line bundle over the Klein bottle; another way to see it is as the mapping cyclinder of the double cover of the Klein bottle by the torus.

Comment: When $M$ admits a complete hyperbolic metric, this is true, but you need the Tameness Theorem for that. In general, I don't know.

Comment: On the other hand, if $S$ is required to be orientable (as suggested by Tom Goodwillie and HJRW), and $M$ admits a complete metric with non-negative sectional curvature, then the claim is true by the Soul Theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll restate the question for the convenience of the reader.$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$

> Suppose that $M$ is a non-compact, connected, oriented three-manifold without boundary, with universal cover homeomorphic to $\RR^3$. Suppose that $F$ is a compact, connected, oriented surface with genus at least one.  Suppose that the fundamental groups of $M$ and $F$ are isomorphic. Is $M$ homeomorphic to $F \times \RR$?

The answer is "no". We can build a counterexample using the paper [Some examples of exotic non-compact three-manifolds](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/40/4/481/1531319) by Scott and Tucker.  Here I closely follow their wording and notation, starting at the bottom of page 488.

Consider their example manifold $M_5$.  This is a three-manifold with boundary a closed surface $F$.  The universal cover of $M_5$ is homeomorphic to $\RR^2 \times \RR_{\geq 0}$, and the inclusion of $F$ into $M_5$ is a homotopy equivalence.  However, $M_5$ is not "almost compact" (that is, it is not tame), and $M_5$ is not homeomorphic to $F \times \RR_{\geq 0}$.

Now double $M_5$ across its boundary to obtain $M = D(M_5)$.  This does not change the fundamental group.  Note that $M$ has two ends, separated by (the image of) $F$.  By Scott-Tucker, neither end is tame.  Thus $M$ is not homeomorphic to $F \times \RR$.  However, the universal cover of the double is (in this case) the double of the universal cover; thus it is $\RR^2 \times \RR$, as desired.

Comment: You may want to add an explanation why the universal cover is $R^3$. (This comes from the fact that the universal cover of $M_5$ is a half-space.)

Comment: Great! I didn't know the reference, thank you.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - good point - added.